# ANDROID STUDIO 3.3 - @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as private in com.android.support:design

Tags: android-studio

I'm a noob trying to get into ANDROID app development. I'm using ANDROID STUDIO 3.3 on WINDOWS 10.

I'm just starting out a new project and in the layout view of my button, I keep getting this error:

@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior is marked as private in com.android.support:design
The error says to change from private to public, but there is a fix. I have researched this and there is a fix on GITHUB, which I downloaded. It has to do with material components android.

So...where do I install this update? I'm looking at my ANDROID3.3 folder, but I can't make out where to overwrite the existing folder.

Thanks for any help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

To do direct changes you need to download the Android sources!

Try to include next line into `build.gradle` (Module: app) script:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

I think you can remove that after you get next Android SDK release (and then return to use new AndroidX library version).

Comment: Thx for the help. I've have looked at build.gradle and located several implementations.